# Creating new column based on value in another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to create new feature columns based on values in a different column. So I have a column with comments, and if they contain a url address, I want to output 1 to the new column, or else output 0, so it would be a binary feature creation.

```
Text                                                        Contains_Url

Buy round lot on the open MT @WSJD #AAPL                               1
stock briefly dove 6.4% today. Analysts 
not sure why https://blogs.wsj.com/moneybeat/
2014/12/01/apple-crash-catches-wall-street-off-guard/

@apple Contact sync between Yosemite and iOS8 is                       0
seriously screwed up. It used to be much more stable 
in the past. #icloud #isync
```

So there would be rows like this and I would like to create a new column in the dataframe with 1 or 0 based on the text column if it has a url or not. Just to check the number of tweets with urls compared to the rest of the dataset, I did

```
data.shape
(3804, 12)
data[data.text.str.contains("http")].shape
(2130, 12)
```

So it shows accurately the number of rows that have a url. My idea was to create a function where I can do this, and apply it using lambda

```
def contains_url(row):
if data[data.text.str.contains("http")]:
    return 1
else:
    return 0

data['contains_url'] = data.apply (lambda row: contains_url(row),axis=1)

ValueError: ('The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty,
a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().', 'occurred at index 0')
```

But doing that is giving me this error above. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this much more efficiently without `apply`, simply by using the boolean value resulting from `str.contains('http')`, and casting it to `int`:

```
data['contains_url'] = data['Text'].str.contains('http').astype(int)
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked perfectly. I guess I didn't need a function after all, I was complicating the problem more than it needed to be!

Comment: if I wanted to extend this, and instead of finding just one string in the column, and wanted to use a different dataframe containing words in a single column, how would I go about doing that? @sacul

Comment: @codingenthusiast, I'm not exactly sure how you mean, your best bet might be to create a [mcve] and post it as a new question, so that we can see your specific requirements :)